# Why does `core.async/pipeline` return a channel?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I just noticed that the `pipeline` family returns a `channel` which seemingly operates completely independently of the purpose of the pipeline and it's related channels.

Notice in the following example you can `>! / <!` from `pipes` and `a> / b>` separately, and they're unrelated.

As far as I understand, `pipeline`s should be a no-op, and return `nil` while setting up the sideffecting `transduc`tion from `a>` to `b>`.

So, what am I missing, and why does `pipeline` return a `channel`?

```
(def a> (chan))
(def b> (chan))
(def pipes (pipeline-blocking 4
                     b>
                     (map clojure.string/upper-case)
                     a>))
(go (>! pipes "hello world"))
(go (println "Pipes: " (<! pipes)))
(go (>! a> "apples are gooood"))
(go (println "B: " (<! b>)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get back a channel which is closed when there are no more elements to copy. That is, after `a>` is closed and all elements from it have been made upper-case and placed onto `b>`. You can `<!` from the resulting channel to find out when the pipelining operation is done, if you care, or you can just throw away the channel. You probably shouldn't write to it.

This is a common pattern for a lot of async operations, and indeed often happens implicitly: every `go` block returns a channel which has the block's return value written to it when the block completes, and many async operations use a `go` block as their return value, so you automatically get this "job done" channel as a result.

Comment: That made sense and gave me enough to run an experiment, which I posted as an answer alongside yours. Please let me know if my explanation is off!

Answer (score 3):

To expound on @amalloy's answer, in the following example, `a>` and `b>` have a `true` put onto them when they are able to complete. Since `chan>` is unbuffered, they can't complete until another process pulls off of them, ie the `println` at the end.

If `chan>` were buffered, `a>` and `b>` can `>!` immediately, so the print immediately.

```
(def chan> (chan 4))
(def a> (go (>! chan> "Apple")))
(go (println "from a>: " (<! a>)))
(def b> (go (>! chan> "Ball")))
(go (println "from b>: " (<! b>)))

(go (println "from chan>: "(<! chan>)))
;; => from chan>: Apple
;; => from a>: true
(go (println "from chan>: "(<! chan>)))
;; => from chan>: Ball
;; => from b>: true
```

This is the same idea behind `pipeline`s.

---

```
;; Pipeline-specific

(def a> (chan))
(def b> (chan))
(def p> (pipeline 4 b> (map clojure.string/upper-case) a>))

;; this won't happen until `a>` `close!`s
(go (println "pipeline is done: " (<! p>)))

;; execute the following 2 lines ad lib
(go (>! a> "hi there"))
(go (println "from b>: " (<! b>)))

(comment
  (close! a>) ; triggers the "pipeline is done"
  (close! b>)) ; doesn't trigger it, but `b>` now only returns nil when taking
```